# hangs problem after logged in

Tags: 12.04, freeze

I installed `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` using `USB` flash drive. The problem is `Ubuntu` stops responding after 1-3 minutes after logging in and it does not respond at all.

### Specifications:

**Processor**:AMD Dual-Core C60

**RAM**:2GB DDR3

Answer (score 0):

This may be driver related.  The C60 uses ATI graphics.  By default, Ubuntu uses the opensource drivers for this chipset.

Try to open up the *Additional Drivers* from the dash and install the official ATI drivers.

Alternatively, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Answer (score 0):

After this step:

"I got out of x by pressing keys like ctrl alt backspace, or ctrl alt del, or ctrl altgr del, or alt F!, or something like that (cant remember whch one worked)"

I install via console using that line "sudo apt-get install fglrx".

I'm using ubuntu now without problems.

Remember to do all updates for last :)

Regards,
Helder